# Unnecessary Stateless Widget Rebuilds (Flutter/Dart) - Possibly StreamBuilder Related?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, stream, rebuild

I am having an issue with very high levels of widget rebuild.  In particular when any navigation between pages happens.

**App Background:**

I am essentially building an app to create and display collections (in this case house plants).  Authentication, database, and image storage are all via Firebase.  This data is then delivered to widgets via streams.  All my custom widgets are currently stateless.

**Summary of Main Page Structure:**

I have a main "library" page that displays this information. This page has a column with a list of "Group" widgets.  The major widget structure for the column looks like this:

1. Group

   - Collection

     - PlantTile
     - PlantTile
   - Collection

     - PlantTile
     - PlantTile
     - PlantTile
2. Group

   - Collection

     - PlantTile
   - Collection

     - PlantTile
     - PlantTile

etc...

Obviously the number of groups, collections, and plantTiles will vary depending on what the user has submitted to the database.

**Problem:**

Every time I navigate between pages in the app, each plant Tile rebuilds not once, but 5 times.  In the example image there are 49 of these tiles, resulting in 245 rebuilds.  The plantTiles are stateless but wrapped in a StreamBuilder to display data.  These widgets contain images and box shadows which seem to be very taxing on the system to rebuild.

[Widget Rebuild Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYc2l.png)

[GridView.builder wraps each plantTile with a StreamBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ws7.jpg)

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plant_collector/formats/constants.dart';
import 'package:plant_collector/screens/plant.dart';
import 'package:plant_collector/widgets/dialogs/select/dialog_select.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:plant_collector/models/ui_builders/builders_general.dart';
import 'package:plant_collector/formats/colors.dart';

class TilePlant extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map plantMap;
  final String collectionID;
  final List<dynamic> possibleParents;
  TilePlant({
    @required this.plantMap,
    @required this.collectionID,
    @required this.possibleParents,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return DialogSelect(
              title: 'Move to Another Collection',
              text:
                  'Please select the collection where you would like to move this plant.',
              plantID: plantMap[kPlantID],
              listBuildColumn: Provider.of<UIBuilders>(context)
                  .createDialogCollectionButtons(
                selectedItemID: plantMap[kPlantID],
                currentParentID: collectionID,
                possibleParents: possibleParents,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: plantMap[kPlantThumbnail] != null
              ? DecorationImage(
                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(plantMap[kPlantThumbnail]))
              : DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/images/default.png',
                  ),
                ),
          boxShadow: kShadowBox,
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        ),
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PlantScreen(
                  plantID: plantMap[kPlantID],
                  forwardingCollectionID: collectionID,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              plantMap[kPlantName] != null
                  ? Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Color(0x44000000),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          maxHeight: 50.0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          plantMap[kPlantName],
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**What I Would Like:**

These widgets have no reason to update.  The point of wrapping in the stream was that after the initial creation, a plantTile should only be updated if a stream event is delivered (the user modifies plant data).  So ideally the widget rebuild of plantTile on navigation would be zero (not 5 x 49 = 245), and if the data of a plant is changed, 1 rebuild.

I have read that there may be an issue with the StreamBuilders firing at every screen build.  I tried to follow other guides to solve this but I must be missing something because I can't seem to stop it.

Any help would be much appreciated!  I am new to this, so hopefully I'm not doing something fundamentally wrong.